# Timer behavior when implementing an RTOS

Tags: embedded, rtos

Assuming I have an RTOS running on an MCU and it has 3 tasks that it should switch between, and say the time spent on each task is 10 ms before moving on to the next task (This includes moving the required register values to and from the stack as needed). No task is prioritized above the other. Now, say I have a timer (TIM) running in the first task that will be executed, from what I understand, the following will happen:

- The timer peripheral will be initialized.
- The timer will start counting.

Now if TIM’s time exceeds that of the time spent per task:

- All the needed registers for the timer will be saved to the stack.
- The other 2 tasks will then be executed.

The timer task will then be re-initiated with all register values as it was before it got interrupted. And let's say the rest of TIM's delay managed to finish before the next task was called.

Now my question is, does this mean that the timer will have an extra 20 ms delay added to it, seeing it first has to do two other tasks that took 10 ms each and because it started the timing process exactly where it left off?

And if so, what techniques can be used to compensate for this?

Comment: I think I'm a bit confused by your overly broad use of the word "timer" for both the physical functional unit "TIM", the thing it does (raising an interrupt after some time), the timer interrupt service routine (ISR), and maybe something else. Can you try to make it clear in your question (edit it, please!) which you mean where? For example, you can't "execute a timer", that makes no sense.

Comment: What makes you think a RTOS will save timer peripheral registers? There is no RTOS doing this, far as I know. They store CPU core registers, SP and the local process stack.

Comment: You are mixing different concepts. There are hardware timers provided by MCU, and these can signal the RTOS which may provide you with software timers. Sometimes they are implemented in a separate timer task. Please be more specific. If you have a specific RTOS in mind, which one?

Comment: If all of your tasks a prioritized equally, and one task is waiting for an event which occurs during the execution of another task, then yes the1st task will end up waiting longer until it gets to execute again. If that's not what you want, then adjust the priorities of your tasks such that the 1st one has higher priority.

Answer (score 2):

### Preface

It's not clear whether this is a thread, process, or task scheduler (and the definition of 'task', and sometimes even 'process', isn't always the same in every textbook either.)

Also, the definition of what qualifies as an RTOS varies. Some simply define it based upon the application. If it is "fast enough" for the application then it is considered to be "real time." I frankly do ***not*** share that definition. And I never will (I've had sufficient arguments with others on this point that my position is now quite firm on this point.) Just looking at the application is a lousy way to define an RTOS, as then even Windows is an RTOS if the application's 'real time' needs are met by it.

Some, would say that an RTOS provides certain specialized features that make it unique when compared with, for example, a workstation O/S. Unique in the sense that they require specialized knowledge held by those who require such an operating system. These might include the ability to schedule the next wake-up at a time relative to some time datum where the O/S provides some guarantees about the *precision* and *variability* of the wake-up and execution start, which is something that Windows, for example, doesn't specify.

### In general

You do seem to be specifying the case where all schedulables are always *ready-to-run* and of equal priority (or put another way are always available to run in *round-robin* fashion.)

An RTOS often allocates one of the timer resources and sets it up a heartbeat timer for the purposes of possible pre-emption and re-scheduling. This timer almost always operates on a fixed, unvarying delta-time, but may be used for a variety of purposes (re-scheduling the run/ready queue, moving processes and/or threads from the sleep/delta queue over to the run/ready queue, etc.)

When the timer event occurs, code in the RTOS will count down the current process's *quantum* and when it reaches zero (or whatever else the author(s) of the O/S might prefer, such as -1) then the RTOS saves whatever it guarantees to save. (This almost always includes the processor registers, including the stack pointer, though in the case of the DEC Alpha for example, it can also includes the current state of the execution pipeline and still more.) Given the equal priority, round-robin behavior, the RTOS will then move the current running process/thread to the end of the ready-to-run queue and remove (or point to) the top process/thread in the ready-to-run queue and set up its quantum to whatever value it is supposed to start with and then the RTOS restores the saved registers and stack (and anything else it saved earlier for that process/thread) and then it starts running from where it left off at.

### More specifically

In your case, you are wondering if this always means that there will be (with your stated assumptions about the total assigned quantum for each process/thread is 10 ms) 30 ms between the last time when a specific process/thread was earlier returned to and when it is next returned to.

If the intervening processes/threads consume their entire quantum (and they all have equal run-time quantums) then you'd be right. However, it's quite common that those processes/threads may also release their remaining quantum back to the RTOS, earlier. They may do this because they completed their work, early. They may do this because they request a resource which isn't immediately available and where they are moved to a different queue to wait for that resource. They may do this because they ask to go to sleep for a time before their quantum expires. And there are more reasons.

So the 30 ms should be the worst case situation, but not necessarily a guaranteed one in the situation you proposed.

### Notes

In the case of threads and in the face of pre-emption (as opposed to cooperative designs), threads which all live within the same process space, there may be both known and unknown library *static* state that needs to be preserved across the pre-emption boundary. These days, libraries tend to be written better than they once were and keep any necessary static state on their thread-stack (or some other thread-local reserved region.) But there is no guarantee of that and some libraries (including standard C libraries) which carry a single instance of important, temporary static state which will be potentially destroyed by another thread using the same library routine during its period of following execution when it is scheduled to run. An RTOS can only save the known parts of such static state. So in the case of very simple RTOS designs, you are either banned from using such library code that isn't designed for multi-threading or else the operating system has to provide explicit guarantees (by preserving such single-instance static state, where known) for library routines of that nature.

This usually isn't nearly as much of a problem now. But it certainly was a huge problem with, for example, the Microsoft C library, years back. And it is something to be aware of today in case you may get caught by the problem when using 3rd party thread-ignorant library code in the face of pre-emption.

A modern case where this problem ***still remains*** is under Windows when using their Win32 form controls. These are all placed in the same process space and their associated code is not multi-thread ready. So they cannot be used directly by MTA (multi-thread apartment) threads. If so, you are almost guaranteed a lot of pain. They handle this by creating an STA (single thread apartment) and using queued message-based RPC calls that are taken in sequence by the STA, unpacked and executed, with results made available to waiting MTA threads, where necessary.

Just a word to the wise. Don't assume when using library functions that they work across pre-emptive re-scheduling boundaries. Hopefully, they do. But don't count on it.

Comment: Thank you for the insight you provided, I learned allot from your explanation and it also answered my question. Can you please provide a source where I can further read up on the subject, thanks.

Comment: @RikusCoetzee This is my own writing. I learned C while working on the Unix v6 kernel in 1978 and I've been writing operating systems ever since then. I've also taught operating systems and concurrent programming professionally as an adjunct professor at the largest university in my state (Oregon.) Perhaps the easiest book to read, if you want to be able to design and write your own, would be Douglas Comer's 1983 (1st edition) on XINU. (Red cover.) Don't buy the later editions, as Dr. Comer removed two important chapters to make room for other material in his later editions.